# Display content inside control when used negative margin.

Tags: wpf, xaml, winrt-xaml

For example I have 2 `Grid`s, like this:

```
<Grid  Height="200" Width="200" Background="Red">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Width="100" Background="Blue" Margin="-30,0,0,0" />
</Grid>
```

And result looks:

[image]

How I can create that content will display only inside control when used negative margin? 
Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using a clip as described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.clip.aspx

Like so:

```
    <Grid  Height="200" Width="200" Background="Red">
        <Grid.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,200,200" />
        </Grid.Clip>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Width="100" Background="Blue" Margin="-30,0,0,0" />
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use ClipToBounds="True" for Grid or other container of elements.

```
  <Grid>  
    <Grid  Height="200" Width="200" Background="Red" ClipToBounds="True">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Width="100" Background="Blue" Margin="-30,0,0,0" />
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```